# Catcher Error Handler in Main() and instantiated variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I started flutter about a month ago and its all going well.I have run into a situation where perhaps a better understanding of when variables are instantiated in Dart/Flutter is required.

I found this cool package called Catcher(https://pub.dev/packages/catcher),it catches exceptions for the whole app with a few lines of code and goes in the Main() and wraps around MyApp() like so

```
void main() {
  CatcherOptions debugOptions = CatcherOptions(
    DialogReportMode(),
    [
      ConsoleHandler(),
      HttpHandler(HttpRequestType.post, Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.47:5000/errorlog"),
          headers: {"UserID": LocalStorage.getUserID()}, printLogs: true)
    ],
  );

  CatcherOptions releaseOptions = CatcherOptions(DialogReportMode(), [
    EmailManualHandler(["joyenergiser101@yahoo.com"])
  ]);

  Catcher(MyApp(), debugConfig: debugOptions, releaseConfig: releaseOptions, enableLogger: true);

}

...
  @override
  void initState() {
    var localStore = LocalStorage();
    LocalStorage.setUserID('69');
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
```

It then sends a post to the rest api and I log it in the DB.All great I love it!

The question I have is why the header part with **LocalStorage.getUserID()** is coming up with a null every time.That value is populated at the point of Login and the error occurs after that. I even Populate it with a value in the main.dart initState()!

Here is the class for LocalStorage

```
class LocalStorage {
 
  static var userID;
  LocalStorage() {
    var userID;
  }
  static String getUserID() {
    return userID;
  }

  static String setUserID(String userid) {
    userID = userid;
  }
}
```

any Idea Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you need to understand is that your `void main()`is the entry point of your application.
Everything you run here is executed before anything else in dart.

The `initState()` you are referring to is probably the initState of MyApp(), or any other widget that gets executed afterward, could you clarify that ?
From what I can see here you simply did not initialize LocalStorage.userId before you use it.

Comment: I think I see what you getting at, the init was indeed for the MyApp.So the Main() is implementing the Catcher wrapper around MyApp , the UserID is only getting set inside myapp but the Catcher has already executed the HttpHandler header before myApp so its null.I think If I want to get a user ID this method wont be succesfull, have to go back to try catch blocks.

Comment: Yup pretty much sums it up. 
How do you expect to set the userID in your app? 
Maybe you could run some logic earlier in your main function ?